# Material UI Datagrid operator not contains

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I use Material UI's datagrid in a project and I found how to use filters like contains, isEmpty and more but I can't find how to make a notContains one.

Does this filter exist natively in Material UI ? Is there a documentation about this or should I make a custom filter by myself ?

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the filters in MUI datagrid.
You should define the custom filter, then add custom filter in `filterOperators` of `columns`.
My custom filter example is
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/material-demo-forked-9v7rkn

And mui doc is following.
https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/filtering/customization/